# How to display callout in Map in android?

Tags: java, android, callout

In my android app, I have created a callout to display in map that displayed in white color, I need to change that black color.

I have take the code from this link https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

I need to change the callout like from the link of image below.
https://lh4.ggpht.com/GFuCZ_CCzcmUg7CZHNKZd7SaeOfb6oXGZ1hat8EToGeROMtCsdI-FC5-jhtDIsT7Gg

How can I do this?

Comment: Try posting code snippets with what you have, and what you have tried. You have to show you really put effort into resolving your issue before asking for help. Also, code snippets might help others in answering quicker to your problem.

Comment: I tried to post the code but the code is not posted, i got error as "code is not formatting"  but i have format the code of XML file

Comment: I have take the code from this link https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons